# Why HWND_NOTTOPMOST cannot bring the window foreground in xp?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using

```
SetWindowPos(m_hParsent, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE)
```

to bring the window foreground, but it does not work in XP System, it work well in my win7.

Comment: Um, you passed the `SWP_NOACTIVATE` flag. This means "Don't bring the window to foreground."

Comment: but it can bring the window foreground on my win7 machine

Comment: um,I just try to remove the NOACTIVE flag, but it still can't bring the window foreground

Comment: Does your process have foreground permission? If all you want to do is set foreground, then why not just call `SetForegroundWindow`?

Comment: I know the SetForegroundWindow, but it will rob the focus, that doesn't meet my requirement.

Comment: Now I'm confused. You say that you want "to bring the window foreground" and now you say that you don't want the window to be foreground?

Answer (score 3):

`HWND_NOTOPMOST` doesn't move a window to the foreground per-se, it simply removes the **topmost** status from a window that has it, and a side effect of this is that the window will be left above other non-topmost windows. But the docs also say "This flag has no effect if the window is already a non-topmost window."

Use `HWND_TOP` to specifically move a window to the top of the z-order, or call `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: But it bring the window foreground on win7 system,and how can I check the window if it is non-topmost.

Comment: And I tried the HWND_TOPMOST and HWND_TOP just now, they does not work either.